# Question About Continuity of an Antiderivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f(x)$ be a periodic function of period $T$ that is integrable over every finite interval. It is clear that $F(x)=\int_x^{x+T} f(x)dx$ is a constant. How can it be shown that $G(x)=\int_0^x f(x)dx$ is a continuous function?

$f(x)$ is integrable over every finite interval, so this ensures that $G(x)$ exists, but I am not sure how to prove that $G(x)$ is continuous. I know that if a function is continuous then it is integrable, but after reading [This page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423155/relation-between-differentiable-continuous-and-integrable-functions), I know this relation doesn't always hold in the opposite direction.

Can I use the fact that since $f(x)$ is integrable over every finite interval, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow x} g(x)$ exists (this is strange to me, since the boundaries of the integral contain the variable) and then $\lim_{x \rightarrow x} g(x)=g(x)$, so then $g(x)$ is continuous at $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that this is about Riemann integral. Riemann integrable functions are bounded. Let $M$ be a bound of $f$, that is, $|f(x)|\le M$. Then for $x<y$
$$
|G(x)-G(y)|=\Bigl|\int_x^yf(t)\,dt\Bigr|\le\int_x^y|f(t)|\,dt\le\int_x^yM\,dx=M\times(y-x).
$$

Comment: In my case, then would $x = 0$ and $y = x$? If so, this gives $M(x)$ at the end, and if $M$ is defined as a continuous function, then this means that $G(x)$ is also continuous?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are any real numbers. $M$ is a number, not a function. The inequality proves that $G$ is a Lipschitz function, and hence continuous.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, thank you. I have never worked with Lipschitz equations before, so I had to read a bit about them.